# What's wrong with or throw new Exception?

Tags: php, exception, throw, parse-error

I'm using this code inside the `public function __construct()` of a `class`:

```
$this->mConnection = mysql_connect(BASE_DB_HOST,BASE_DB_USER,BASE_DB_PASS) or throw new Exception("Couldn't connect to database.");
```

`BASE_DB_HOST`, `BASE_DB_USER` and `BASE_DB_PASS` are defined. I get the following error:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_THROW in **/home/...** on line **6**

Am I not allowed to use the `or` construction with Exceptions? How can I workaround this?

Comment: `$connection = mysql_connect(BASE_DB_HOST,BASE_DB_USER,BASE_DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't connect to database.")`;

Comment: I want to use an exception. Is something similar possible? And why isn't this possible?

Comment: `throw` is a statement, `or` needs to be followed by an expression.

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions, if you use pdo you get exceptions for free.

Comment: Closing this as "Too localized" makes no sense at all, this is quite common

Comment: The resolution for [this bug/feature req.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72589) was 'submit an RFC'. It's a deep change to have statements (like `throw`, `return`) mixed with expressions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using like this and let me know if its work for you or not-

```
<?php
function throwException() {
    throw new Exception("Couldn't connect to database.");
}

$this->mConnection = mysql_connect(BASE_DB_HOST,BASE_DB_USER,BASE_DB_PASS) OR throwException();
?>
```

Reference - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#81960

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to throw an exception in an anonymous function after the `or` logical operator.

```
$this->mConnection = mysql_connect(BASE_DB_HOST,BASE_DB_USER,BASE_DB_PASS) or call_user_func(function() { throw new Exception("Couldn't connect to database."); });
```